# Device orientation sensor to CSS transform

Tags: javascript, css, 3d, transform, orientation

I've created [the following widget (see demo here)](https://3bcyb.codesandbox.io/) to mimic the sensors tab on the chrome developer tab:

---

[image]

---

My code listens to the orientation event of the device and tries to convert the values to fit the css transform scale, like so:

```
let phone = document.querySelector(".phone");
    window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', (event) => {
      phone.style.transform =
        "rotateY(" + ( event.alpha) + "deg) "
        +
        "rotateX(" + (90 - event.beta) + "deg) "
        +
        "rotateZ(" + (event.gamma ) + "deg)";
    })
```

However, if I play around enough with the values, my widget and the chrome widget get out of sync. Obviously, my calculations are wrong, what am I missing?

To test my code, just go to the [demo](https://3bcyb.codesandbox.io/) open the dev tools sensors tab and play around with the widget.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**
to get to the sensors tab: Open dev tools, press Esc, on the second panel click the 3dots on the left and choose sensors.

**Update:**
Example of problematic values are:
alpha: -77.6163
beta:-173.4458
gamma:-40.4889

Comment: Luckily we can study [the source code for this dev tool](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/e39d83de0ff263f20181a56482d89a1c62bb0363/third_party/blink/renderer/devtools/front_end/emulation/SensorsView.js#L370)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how it is done in chromium and chrome:

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vqXEGv)

Essential part there is that when we apply `gamma` angle transformation, the axis is already rotated by previous `beta` angle transformation. So we need to apply gamma rotation angle not to `(0, 0, 1)` axis but to transformed axis which considers beta angle.

Source:

```js
function degreesToRadians (deg) {
    return deg * Math.PI / 180;
}

class EulerAngles {
  constructor(alpha, beta, gamma) {
    this.alpha = alpha;
    this.beta = beta;
    this.gamma = gamma;
  }
  
  toRotate3DString() {
    const gammaAxisY = -Math.sin(degreesToRadians(this.beta));
    const gammaAxisZ = Math.cos(degreesToRadians(this.beta));
    const axis = {
      alpha: [0, 1, 0],
      beta: [-1, 0, 0],
      gamma: [0, gammaAxisY, gammaAxisZ]
    };
    return (
      "rotate3d(" +
      axis.alpha.join(",") +
      "," +
      this.alpha +
      "deg) " +
      "rotate3d(" +
      axis.beta.join(",") +
      "," +
      this.beta +
      "deg) " +
      "rotate3d(" +
      axis.gamma.join(",") +
      "," +
      this.gamma +
      "deg)"
    );
  }
}

function ready(fn) {
  if (
    document.attachEvent
      ? document.readyState === "complete"
      : document.readyState !== "loading"
  ) {
    fn();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
  }
}

ready(() => {
  let phone = document.querySelector(".phone");
  window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", event => {
    console.log(event);
    const eulerAngles = new EulerAngles(event.alpha, -90 + event.beta, event.gamma)
    phone.style.transform = eulerAngles.toRotate3DString();
  });
});
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly, However, when I test a real device I get unexpected results (landscape when in portrait mode in some cases)

Comment: I see that behavior as well. But those are sensors values (even debug tool is in landscape mode with the same angles)

Comment: I'll try to figure it out, and will let you know

Comment: here is what I've found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56651738/device-orientation-data-transformed-to-css-behaves-strange-when-using-a-real-dev

Comment: That's awesome! Did quaternion fix the problem with real device?